# Dropping column gives Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data of the form:

```
red_id            test1 test2   test3......
815298969_mid1    pass  fail    pass
815298969_mid2    fail  pass    pass
815298969_final   pass  pass    pass
814248989_mid1    pass  fail    fail
814248989_mid2    pass  fail    pass
814248989_final   pass  pass    fail
816592961_mid1    fail  pass    pass
816592961_mid2    pass  pass    pass
816592961_final   pass  pass    pass
......
```

I have a pandas dataframe with above student details and i'm grouping it by column 'red_id'

```
    grouped = data_frame.groupby('red_id')
```

.....
Then in my script I have loop

```
for red, stud_data in grouped:
......
        data = data.drop('red_id', axis=1)
```

and I'm trying to drop a column 'red_id'from a dataframe because i want class average for pass/fail in for loop as shown above.
It's giving me exception:

```
Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Comment: could you add example so we can reproduce this case?

Comment: @RomanPekar I have updated my question. It is working sometimes and sometimes doesn't. can you suggest me a way to solve this issue

Comment: actually it's still not an example. There's even no data variable in your code. I suggest you to add small example where we can easily reproduce the bug. It would be even better if you add your input and desired output

Comment: @RomanPekar Now I I have posted my data. can you suggest me a way now?